# Return response from Axios and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

I'm trying to get something simple done with Axios but no luck. I want to get a response back from Axios call and assign it to a variable and do something with it next outside of the function block.

```
const axios = require("axios");
var posts;
(async () => {
  const allPosts = await axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  posts = allPosts;
})()
// do something with posts here
```

I know because the func is async we get to `// do something with posts here` first but then how we can work with the response outside of async function

Answer (score 1):

You can consider use callback function, like below code snippet:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

(async () => {
  const allPosts = await axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  someThingYouWantToDo(allPosts);
})()

const someThingYouWantToDo = (posts) => {
  console.log(posts);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would assign `posts` to a state variable *inside* the async function right after receiving the data, and that would trigger a re-render. Or you would call a redux dispatch action to set the value in redux and redux would update the props. So in short, it's the usual React way: update state or props to render the view, use `componentDidUpdate` for any additional logic. For example:

```
const axios = require("axios");
var posts;
(async () => {
  const allPosts = await 
  axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  posts = allPosts;
  this.setState({
    posts,
  })
})()
```

Comment: Oops! You are right! I didn't notice he using react!

Comment: Sorry, wrong tag. I need to add this piece of code to a Node function

Answer (score 0):

Given this is node, and not React as the original tag suggested, it could be as easy as:

```
const axios = require("axios");
var posts;
await (async () => {
  const allPosts = await axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  posts = allPosts;
})();
// do something with posts
```

Comment: I don't think you can use await outside of an async function

Comment: True. Though it's almost always trivial to put it inside one.